# Pattern matching consecutive characters

Tags: perl

I have a list of strings that I would like to search through and ignore any that contain A or G characters that occur more than 4 times consecutively. For instance, I would like to ignore strings such as TCAAAATC or GCTGGGGAA.

I've tried:

```
unless ($string =~ m/A{4,}?/g || m/G{4,}?/g)
{
    Do something;
}
```

But I get an error message "Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)".

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your `$string` variable set to a defined value?

Comment: Yes. $string is set to each line of the file that I am searching through.

Answer (score 3):

You need to avoid the implicit comparison with `$_`, which you can do by writing:

```
unless ($string =~ m/A{4}/ || $string =~ m/G{4}/)
```

This looks for exactly 4 A's or exactly 4 G's in the string; if there are 4, it doesn't matter whether there are any more than 4.

You can reduce it to a single regular expression by using:

```
unless ($string =~ m/([AG])\1{3}/)
```

which looks for an A or G followed by 3 more of the same character.

Comment: I actually like `A{4}|G{4}` better; it's a bit more explicit and a bit less magical.

Comment: With a repeat count of only 4, I'm not sure we could demonstrate a performance difference, but I'd suspect that the alternation is slower if the count was 400.  I live to be proved wrong, of course.  But I agree it is easier to understand.

Comment: Yeah, well, I don't tend to think about Perl matching performance much. The Perl regex core tends to do a lot of esoteric optimizations which may result in surprising behaviour.

Comment: Hmmm...well, I lose...I measured (1) `m/([AG])\1{127}/` vs (2) `m/A{128}|G{128}` vs (3) `m/A{128}/ || m/G{128}`, on just over 1 MiB of data with 3072 lines that matched out of 9126 lines in the file, and (1) is over 100 times slower (1.630 s vs 0.012 s), but (2) and (3) are neck-and-neck.

Comment: Wow. Guess the backreference really hurts performance...good to know. Kind of amazing that 2 and 3 are so close.

Comment: Yes; it is surprising.  In fact, if anything, (3) is faster, but I was testing A's first, so if the A's matched, it didn't need to look at the G's (and there were more A-lines than G-lines), which may have something to do with it.   I was quite surprised at the discrepancy.  It just goes to show that measurement is vital.

Answer (score 3):

By writing

```
|| m/G{4,}?/g
```

you are implicitly testing `$_` against this regex. But, `$_` is not initialized, so you get an error.

Write

```
unless ($string =~ m/A{4}/ || $string =~ m/G{4}/)
```

instead (note the simplifications made to the regex), or, as a single expression,

```
unless ($string =~ m/A{4}|G{4}/)
```

Comment: You don't want the `?` in there, do you? It means 0 or 1 consecutive occurrences of 4 A's or 4 G's, doesn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: it means "non-greedy" as it occurs after a quantifier. It's probably not necessary.

Comment: Oh, yes...but with nothing following it, the greediness or non-greediness is immaterial.

Comment: Yep, I know. So it's useless, and so I removed it. I think the `/g` is also useless because the match only needs to happen once.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the ? and /g is not necessary when I think about it. As long as it finds the first occurrence, I can throw the string out and ignore it. Thank you!